# Whenever I try to set foreign key constraint to "NO ACTION" MySQL workbench automatically sets it to "RESTRICT"

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, relational-database, mysql-workbench

I am trying to set a foreign key to constraint for on delete and on update to "NO ACTION", but for some reason after I apply the changes MySQL workbench changes it back to "RESTRICTED" on its own, I don't know why it's doing that.

This is the code MySQL Workbench generates when I try to change the constraints for on update and on delete to "NO ACTION"

```sql
ALTER TABLE `forums`.`post_replies` 
DROP FOREIGN KEY `fk_post_replies_users`;
ALTER TABLE `forums`.`post_replies` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_post_replies_users`
  FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
  REFERENCES `forums`.`users` (`id`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NO ACTION` and `RESTRICT` are synonyms.

["13.1.20.5 FOREIGN KEY Constraints"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html):

> `NO ACTION`: A keyword from standard SQL. In MySQL, equivalent to `RESTRICT`.

Workbench seems to just pick to display `RESTRICT` over `NO ACTION` (well, it has to chose one and chooses the MySQL specific one...). But it doesn't mean anything different.

Comment: What if I want it to do nothing when the parent row is deleted? If a user wants their account deleted for example, I don't want all their posts to be deleted

Comment: @InfinityVive: Well something *has* to be done as otherwise there'd be inconsistent data. An option would be `ON DELETE SET NULL` that'l "disconnect" the posts form the user so that the user can be deleted. Or consider just "soft" deleting the user. i.e. don't really `DELETE` it but `UPDATE` some flag that indicates the user isn't active anymore. Filter for that flag in queries that should work only on active users.

Comment: " do nothing when the parent row is deleted" Then you don't have a Foreign Key. Don't declare it in the first place. @sticky bit's 'soft' delete is good.